# WebView2 - Get an attribute

Tags: javascript, webview2

I am trying to understand the architecture in WebView2. With WebBrowser i used to get an attribute from a result returned by the GetElementById as follows: `Document.GetElementById("DropDownList").GetAttribute("selectedIndex")`

I know that the `ExecuteScriptAsync` in WebView2 can run a javascript and return a result as a string. However, it looks like that it does not know how to get an attribute from an element. The below code returns a null. Although, the getElementById returns the correct result.
`ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('DropDownList').getAttribute('selectedIndex')")`

Is my syntax incorrect? How to get an attribute in WebView2?. Do we have to write a function in the script and call it from the host?

Thanks

Comment: You JavaScript never worked with Webbrowser either. -1 from me.

Comment: @darbid: Actually in the old WebBrowser, you used C# to access the dom, not javascript (the code shown is C#).

Comment: I was referring to this “Although, the getElementById returns the correct result.”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `HTMLSelectElement` does not have an attribute called.'selectedIndex'. It has a PROPERTY called 'selectedIndex'.

Call it like this from `WebView2`:

```
await webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('DropDownList').selectedIndex");
```

Many people are confused about javascript `attributes` versus `properties`. Simple rule (easy to remember) is:

**Attributes can be written directly in the html tag, like 'id', 'name' etc. Properties are set by runtime.**

Comment: Awesome! that worked! Thanks!. You are very knowledgeable in WebView2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to await this method. [see the reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.executescriptasync)

```
string res = await ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('DropDownList').getAttribute('selectedIndex')")
```

Comment: yes, I am already awaiting this method. As I explained getElementById returns a value but if I add a getAttribute it returns null

Comment: Then you have a JavaScript problem. Navigate to the site, open dev tools, go to console and paste your JavaScript and press enter. What happens?